# Why a ggplot is not showing here?

Tags: python, ggplot2, plot

I am using code from [here](https://pypi.org/project/lets-plot/#start) trying to produce a simple plot:

```
from lets_plot import *
LetsPlot.setup_html()        

import numpy as np
np.random.seed(12)

data = dict(
    cond=np.repeat(['A','B'], 200),
    rating=np.concatenate((np.random.normal(0, 1, 200), np.random.normal(1, 1.5, 200)))
)

ggplot(data, aes(x='rating', fill='cond')) + ggsize(500, 250) \
+ geom_density(color='dark_green', alpha=.7) + scale_fill_brewer(type='seq') \
+ theme(axis_line_y='blank')
```

I am running this code from a standalone file using command line:

```
python3 mycode.py
```

It runs without any error but no plot shows up. I have also tried following but it does not work:

```
gg = ggplot(....
print(gg)
```

Above outputs data and layers on console but no plot is shown.

Adding following also does not help:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Where is the problem and how can I get a plot to be displayed with above code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package seems to depend on JavaScript(JS) for displaying visulisations and seems to be built to supprt online notebooks as it says on the github page - [Lets-Plot meant for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N59QI.png)

However, there does seem to be a [plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIvAW.png) available for pycharm and IntelliJ IDEA but the one on pycharm is available only in professional version.

So with this new information, I have tried running an instance of Jupyter notebook online and running the same piece of code produces the [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ex6ct.png) is expected.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow and thanks for a good answer.